# php ldap trying to display list of ou's and sub ou's

Tags: php, ldap

I am trying to display list of Ou's and sub Ou's. I have written as below, but something is wrong.

I am having ldap structure like :  `cn=test,ou=sub-group1,ou=group1,dc=mycomp,dc=com`

```
 $dn = "ou=group1,dc=mycomp,dc=com"; 
 $filter="(objectClass=organizationalunit)"; 
 $justthese = array("dn", "ou"); 
 $sr=ldap_search($ldapconn, $dn, $filter, $justthese); 
 $info = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $sr); 

for ($i=0; $i < $info["count"]; $i++) { 
        echo $info[$i]["dn"]."<br>"; 
}
```

Please suggest me what went wrong.

Comment: What's happening? Are you getting an error message, or empty results? Nothing about that specifically looks wrong at first glance.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the rights to search and read the directory tree? For example, does an equivalent search using a command line tool like `ldapsearch` give you the expected results?